# Get Javascript variable inside json

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, wordpress

I have a `json` file that has about twenty objects like this:

```
{
"firstName": "User1",
"lastName" : "UserLname",
"title": "Human",
"description": "Something Facinating",
"photoURL": "http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/profile/user1.jpg",
"contact": {
     "email" : "user1@example.com"
      }
}
```

I have a javascript code to display images/description from these objects to a page. I want this site to be uploaded in more than one place. So it doesn't make sense for me to use absolute url in this `json` file. I overcame the issue in `js` by passing a variable `templateUrl` from `header.php` file and calling it inside the javascript file.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var templateUrl = '<?= get_bloginfo("template_url"); ?>';
</script>
```

And in javascript:`$.getJSON(templateUrl+"/scripts/file.json", function(file){....}`

I want a way to pass this `templateUrl` variable to `json` file too. So I can have image path set to just `images/profile/user1.jpg`, and I can prepend the url to this depending on where the site is uploaded.

Comment: *`"I want a way to pass this template variable to json file too"`* And where this JSON file is coming from?

Comment: it's inside the script folder too. It has an array of objects like above.

Comment: Simply open your `file.json` and edit to remove the absolute path... Or is this file dynamically generated?

Comment: No the script file is not dynamically generated. It's not the location of json I am worried about, it's the location of images.

Comment: Change `"photoURL": "http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/profile/user1.jpg"` to `"photoURL": "images/profile/user1.jpg"` in the JSON file. Otherwise, I think I'm misunderstanding your Q.

Comment: Reading again your response, I think I misunderstood your response. Wouldn't that change the file permanently? Is there a way to let the file remain as is? so I could just copy the template folder some place and it would still work. I am using `ICanHaz.js` to display the names and stuff fyi.

Comment: If you don't want the file 'permanently changed' what do you want accomplished exactly? Do you want a way to remove the base url dynamically after you've loaded the json instead?

Comment: yes I would like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#json.php
{
"firstName": "User1",
"lastName" : "UserLname",
"title": "Human",
"description": "Something Facinating",
"photoURL": "<?= $_GET['var']; ?>/images/profile/user1.jpg",
"contact": {
     "email" : "user1@example.com"
      }
}
```

```
#main page
<script type="text/javascript">
var templateUrl = encodeURI("http://example.com");

$(function(){
    $.getJSON(
        'json.php?var=' + templateUrl,

        function(data){
            $.each(data, function(key, val){
                console.log(key + ": " + val);
            });
        }
    );
});

</script>
```

Output:

```
firstName: User1
lastName: UserLname
title: Human
description: Something Facinating
photoURL: http://example.com/images/profile/user1.jpg
contact: [object Object]
```

Comment: How is this relevant to my question? I still can't use the variable inside `json`, right? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Sorry, I hope I have not misinterpreted your question. Please take a look at the edited suggestion though, it's less generic now. The essence is to change "file.json" to "whatever.php" in order to pass a variable. I hope it helps.

Comment: This doesn't exactly answers my question. But I know where to go from here. Thanks. :)